# How to enable UI for flowable?

Tags: spring-boot, flowable

is it possible to add ui tools to existing spring boot application with flowable engine ?
Added dependencies , but spring complains that resources ar not FOUND(404)

```
implementation group: 'org.flowable', name: 'flowable-spring-boot-starter-ui-task', version: '6.7.2'
implementation group: 'org.flowable', name: 'flowable-spring-boot-starter-process-rest', version: '6.7.2'
implementation group: 'org.flowable', name: 'flowable-spring-boot-starter-ui-admin', version: '6.7.2'
implementation group: 'org.flowable', name: 'flowable-spring-boot-starter-ui-modeler', version: '6.7.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't. Because Flowable Engine and REST API wrapper (`flowable-rest.war`) - is core product. But, `flowable-ui.war`, is independent product to demonstrate ability of Flowable, and inner UI part implemented using AngularJS.

Comment: actually we enabled it , will try to share soon

Comment: @LvDevR1 please provide solution if you have done

Answer (score 0):

```html
implementation "org.flowable:flowable-spring-boot-starter-ui-admin:$flowableVersion"
    implementation "org.flowable:flowable-spring-boot-starter-ui-idm:$flowableVersion"
    implementation "org.flowable:flowable-spring-boot-starter-ui-modeler:$flowableVersion"
    implementation "org.flowable:flowable-spring-boot-starter-ui-task:$flowableVersion"
```

```
and in properties :
flowable:
  admin:
    app:
      security:
        encryption:
          credentials-i-v-spec: 
          credentials-secret-spec:
```